# Integration testing with different versions of gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, integration-testing

I'm working on a gem which depends on Rails and Rack. I would like to write bunch of integration tests which would be automatically run on different versions of rails and rack gems. Do you know any good read about this or have some experiences in this topic?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like thoughtbot's [appraisal gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/appraisal) is the kind of thing you're looking for.

Set up your gems:

```
appraise "rails-3" do
  gem "rails", "3.2.14"
end

appraise "rails-4" do
  gem "rails", "4.0.0"
end
```

Then run your tests:

```
appraisal rails-3 rake test
```